# Compile ObjectiveC hello world on iPad 2

Tags: objective-c, ipad, gcc, toolchain

I'm trying to compile a ObjectiveC hello world on a jailbroken iPad 2.

The gcc already works for c/c++ on my iPad. I got OpenEXR built without problems.
I copied framework headers/lib from iPhoneOS 4.2 SDK and installed "iPhone 2.0 Toolchain".

With the command:

```
gcc -I/private/var/include -framework Foundation hello.m
```

I got 2 kinds of errors:

```
ld warning: bad symbol version: $ld$add$os3.2$_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSURL in dylib /System/Library/Frameworks//Foundation.framework/Foundation
ld: file not found: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
```

Where I can find the file "libobjc.A.dylib" or am I missing anything in the toolchain?

Comment: From the code you've posted, there's a double forward slash in your reference to the Foundation framework; as for the library file, search your Mac and/or Developer folder, you should find it in there.

Comment: The problem is I don't have a Mac yet... I assume the library file is available in the iOS SDK package, but didn't find it yet.

Comment: Finally, I found it's in the SDK package, but search "objc" on windows explorer returns nothing for libraries... Thanks anyway, Luke!

Comment: Glad you sorted it - post your comment as an answer and accept it if you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to find the missing lib from /var/sdk/usr/lib and copy or symlink it over the required path. Beware when you mix the "cydia" toolcahin and an SDK as you might not get what you expected (usually, a lot of warning and more libs to symlink).
This is because the tools (mostly ld) think that you're using the 2.0 toolchain and warn for methods which have been introduced later.